# how to make search faster from contactList for given string

Tags: java, sorting, search, collections

I have ContactList which contains contacts with firstName and lastName. I want to perform search by FirstName or lastName.

I have already written code which works fine but I want to improve search in terms of speed and memory.

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String name;

    public Contact(String name) {

        this.name = name;
        if (name.contains(" ")) {
            this.firstName = name.split("\\s+")[0];
            this.lastName = name.split("\\s+")[1];
        } else {
            this.firstName = name;
            this.lastName = "";
        }
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact{" + name + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Contact contact) {
        System.out.println("in compareto");
        return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(contact.getName());
    }
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (firstName.hashCode() * (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0));
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == null)
        return false;
    if(!(obj instanceof Contact)) 
        return false;

    Contact other = (Contact) obj;
    if(! this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(other.name)) return false;

    return true;
}
  }

public class ContactService {

    private Set<Contact> contacts;

    public ContactService() {
        this.contacts =  new TreeSet<>();
    }

    public void addContact(String name) {
        Contact contact = new Contact(name);
        contacts.add(contact);
    }

    public void searchContact(String searchStr) {
        System.out.println(contacts);
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            if (contact.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchStr)||(searchStr.contains(" ") && contact.getName().contains(searchStr))) {
                System.out.println(contact.getName());
            } else if (contact.getFirstName().toLowerCase().startsWith(searchStr) || contact.getLastName().toLowerCase().startsWith(searchStr)) {
                System.out.println(contact.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest how to improve performance in above code.

Comment: You could also use indexing to faster your search. However, You need not to care if your list is less than 10k elements since the search time is pretty small.

Comment: I was thinking to add indexing but I am not sure on what field i need to put indexes firstName or lastName?

Comment: @Kilanny as you can see user can search by lastName or firstName  so do i need to have two index if yes then we need to traverse the list two times .

Comment: No. You need to have index on the *combined* firstname and lastname. You can use this lib also https://lucene.apache.org/core/

Comment: I am using plain java code so need to write my own code.

Comment: Yes, and using the lib is also "pain java code" :) It is as much as simply calling the methods defined in the lib, rather than re-inventing the wheel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115628/discussion-between-manojp-and-kilanny).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `java.util.HashMap`, to store a lookup table for Contacts for search terms.

The idea is to pre-populate the  lookup table with likely search terms (e.g. the first name or the first three letters of the name). If your lookup doesn't return any matches you can always perform a full search. If you want more powerful searching you could look at something like [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/).

E.g.

```
Map<String, Set<Contact>> contactLookup = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you'd start by looking up the search term in the map. This would narrow down the possibilities to a small set which you can iterate over using the same method you use above.

You might also look at the [`Multimap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) from Guava, which provides the same capability more elegantly.

---

By the way (on an unrelated note) when you override the `compareTo()` method it is good practice to also override `equals()` so that 
`(x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))`.

And when you override `equals()` you will also need to override `hashCode()`!

Comment: I dont have predefined searchTerms, my requirement is like User entered contacts like "Manoj Pathak", "Manoj". 
If user type "Man"  and hit search  then result will be 
Manoj Pathak
Manoj 

If user type "Manoj"  and hit search  then result will be 
Manoj (exact match)
Manoj Pathak

Comment: I have updated code for equals and hashcode. What value need to be set in map's key as  searchTerm ??

Comment: Search terms (keys) might be, for example: "manoj", "man", "pathak". All of these keys would point to the same Contact.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont have predefined searchTerms, my requirement is like User
>   entered contacts like "Manoj Pathak", "Manoj". If user type "Man" and
>   hit search then result will be Manoj Pathak Manoj If user type "Manoj"
>   and hit search then result will be Manoj (exact match) Manoj Pathak"

In this case I will suggest you implement    **Longest prefix matching – A Trie based solution in Java** which internally will use HashMap.